# How does the struct function greater work in this piece of code?

Tags: c++, struct, merge

I have this piece of code and I don't understand the purpose of the function `greaters` in it. Wouldn't it be enough to reverse sort each stack and then merge them as usual?

What does the struct function greaters do in this case?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// comparator function to reverse merge sort
struct greaters {
    bool operator()(const long& a, const long& b) const
    {
        return a > b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // initializing 1st container
    vector<int> arr1 = { 1, 4, 6, 3, 2 };

    // initializing 2nd container
    vector<int> arr2 = { 6, 2, 5, 7, 1 };

    // declaring resultant container
    vector<int> arr3(10);

    // sorting initial containers
    // in descending order
    sort(arr1.rbegin(), arr1.rend());
    sort(arr2.rbegin(), arr2.rend());

    // using merge() to merge the initial containers
    // returns descended merged container
    merge(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), arr2.begin(), arr2.end(), arr3.begin(), greaters());

    // printing the resultant merged container
    cout << "The container after reverse merging initial containers is : ";

    for (int i = 0; i < arr3.size(); i++)
        cout << arr3[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: it is a constraint to marge values in a two container, take a look at merge sort merging algorithm.

Comment: @NishanthShetty This isn't a merge sort algorithm. It just merges already sorted ranges.

Comment: @juanchopanza i haven't mentioned that its a merge sort algorithm, i asked OP to take a look at that algorithm which will help OP to understand the above piece of code.

Comment: "... and then merge them as usual" - what does that mean? If you sort two sequences in *descending* order and then merge them "as usual", i.e. by selecting *minimal* value from each sequence, you will get nonsensical results. Two sequences: `{ 5, 3 }`, `{ 6, 2 }`. Merge "as usual": `{ 5, 3, 6, 2 }`. That's a rather useless result.

Comment: Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, ever.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I know, it wasn't I who wrote the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try running it without the comparison operator (`struct greaters`)? You will find you get this:

```
6 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 2 1 // Equivalent of [arr1][arr2]
```

Instead of this:

```
7 6 6 5 4 3 2 2 1 1
```

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/5swJNA)

The struct provides a comparison function object, that the function will use to merge in a desired way. It will use the comparison operator something like this:

```
while values left in arr1 && arr2
    if (arr1[currentR1_reference] > arr2[currentR2_reference]) {
                                  ^ (compare operator)
        add arr1[currentR1_reference]
        move onto the next value in arr1
    } else {
        add arr2[currentR2_reference]
        move onto the next value in arr2

 Add whatever is left of arr1 or arr2
```

See [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge):

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second. 
>   The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

> The signature does not need to have const &, but the function object must not modify the objects passed to it.
>   The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that objects of types InputIt1 and InputIt2 can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both Type1 and Type2. ​